# Optimizing button.titleLabel

Tags: ios, performance, uibutton, autolayout, instruments

I am optimizing my app on iPhone 4, it's really fast on iPhone 5 but lagging a little on iPhone 4. Using instrument Time Profiler, I found that 30% of the time is spent on [UIButton titleLabel], it seems huge for a UIKit simple task
I am calling several times button.titleLabel.font and [button.titleLabel setFont:font]; but I don't see why using pointers would take so long. How would you optimise this?
My app is using autolayout.

[image]

[image]

edit: it seems most of the performance goes into calling UIButton.titleLabel which triggers autolayout constraint calculation

Comment: Can you get any more fine-grained? What I find is that creating the font can be time-consuming; this is easily remedied by making the font beforehand and keeping a reference to it. Might that help?

Comment: I'll try keeping the font, but all this times I am accessing the font from the font of other label. It's that a problem

Comment: What I'm asking is whether you can be more specific about what you think is taking time. `titleLabel` is rather vague; it is, as you say, just a pointer, which is readily available, so it's hard to believe that _this_ is what needs optimizing. Can you post a screen shot of what Instruments tells you?

Comment: "I don't think it should impact any thing" - wait, you're adding a delay and then you're surprised there's a delay?

Comment: First, the time is apparently being spent in `setFont:`, not in `titleLabel`. Second, the really informative stuff is the breakdown by actual calls, like this: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/figs/pios_0912.png

Comment: Here's a thought - do things behave any better if you do this (QuestionViewController's configuration) in its `viewWillAppear:` instead of doing it in its `viewDidLoad`? You might have to use a BOOL flag to prevent this setup from occurring on subsequent calls to `viewWillAppear:`, but for purposes of experiment, just move it all to `viewWillAppear:` and see if the "lag" gets any better.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did move the QuestionViewController's configuration in viewWillAppear but it didn't change much. However it's seems all the lag come from autolayout constraint calculation. I removed some setNeedsDisplay and it seems to perform a little better

Comment: @matt I removed the UIButton.titleLabel putting all the font and numberOfLines in the xib. It's much faster now. I guess getting UIButton.titleLabel triggers some Autolayout calculation.

Comment: I get the very same result, and the code in question is VERY simple: UILabel* foo = self.myButton.titleLabel. (self.myButton is an IBOutlet, so the theory about autolayout being triggered is reasonable).

Comment: I got the same performace problem when call button's titleLabel and imageView whihout doing any thing(Using autolayout)